# Welcome Message isn't work because GetUpdates Telegram Bot API can't record joined notification update in supergroup

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, telegram-api

Few days ago i made a telegram bot with python using api from https://core.telegram.org/bots/api.
All the code works perfectly until i realize that the GetUpdates api didn't record the joined notification for the new user in my group

My plan is to made a welcome message to new user based on those record. The group not allowing user to send message (broadcast group) and right now i confused that i can't get any single record related to the new user joined, so then the welcome message didn't work perfectly

This is my function for getUpdates api and the welcome message

```
    def get_updates(self, offset=0, timeout=50):
        method = 'getUpdates'
        params = {'timeout': timeout, 'offset': offset}
        resp = requests.get(self.api_url + method, params)
        result_json = resp.json()['result']
        return result_json

    def welcome_msg(self, item):
        chat_id = item["message"]["chat"]["id"]
        user_id = item["message"]["new_chat_member"]["id"]
        if "username" in item["message"]["new_chat_member"]:
            user_name = item["message"]["new_chat_member"].get("username", user_id)
        else:
            user_name = item["message"]["new_chat_member"].get("first_name", user_id)
        welcom_msg = "HI WELCOME TO THIS GROUP"
        to_url3 = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot{}/sendMessage?chat_id={}&text={}&parse_mode=HTML&disable_web_page_preview=True'.format(token, chat_id, welcom_msg)
        resp3 = requests.get(to_url3)
```

And after that the welcome message should be like this

```
new_offset = 1
all_updates = get_updates(new_offset)
if len(all_updates) > 0:
   for current_update in all_updates:
     first_update_id = current_update['update_id']
     if old_id < first_update_id:
       old_id = int(current_update['update_id'])
       try:
         if "new_chat_member" in current_update['message']:
           welcome_msg(current_update)
           chat_id = current_update["message"]["chat"]["id"]
           message_id = current_update["message"]["message_id"]
           new_offset = first_update_id + 1
       except:
         pass
```

Does the restriction of the group (member can't send message) made the getUpdates API couldn't work and the welcome message didn't showing up???

Answer (score 0):

Go to botfather, bot settings and set privacy mode off for this bot, It should work